# AngularJS 1.2.1 - dynamically adding directives errors unless they do not replace source element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have upgraded my application to AngularJS 1.2.1 and am running into an issue with previously working code, which I am unable to solve.

I have a page where the user builds up the content from a pre-defined list of content, each of which is a separate AngularJS directive.  I have a service which stores the array of configured items and have this linked to an ng-repeat command.  All I am doing when the user chooses to add a new item is push it onto the array and leave it up to Angular to update the UI.  My HTML is similar to this.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in configuration">
    <directive-a data-ng-if="item.obj === 'directive-a'></directive-a>
    <directive-b data-ng-if="item.obj === 'directive-b'></directive-b>
    <directive-c data-ng-if="item.obj === 'directive-c'></directive-c>
    <directive-d data-ng-if="item.obj === 'directive-d'></directive-d>
</div>
```

All of the directives here inherit parent scope, and are about as simple as they come.

```
angular.module("App").directive("directiveA", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "partials/DriectiveA.html"
    };
});
```

When I have them set to replace 'true', I get the following error in the console upon adding them to the array and the item does not render:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at ngRepeatAction (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/angular-1.2.1.js:18826:15)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/angular-1.2.1.js:11347:11)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/angular-1.2.1.js:11443:27)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/angular-1.2.1.js:11682:24)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/angular-1.2.1.js:17531:21)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/jQuery-1.8.2.js:3063:34)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle.eventHandle (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/js/libs/jQuery-1.8.2.js:2681:47)
```

Line 9101, which is in a "consoleLog" function, so it appears to be failing to write something to the console, failing, but managing to write the error there anyway!  I've tried debugging it and can't actually manage to get it to.

When I have them set to replace 'false', it works fine.  I want them to replace the source element otherwise the formatting is a real pain because of the extra element, and was able to do so prior to the upgrade.

Can anyone offer any advice here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if you wrap your html template in a div then it'll work fine.  Or if you have have the template in the directive instead of using templateUrl.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve this with the current code, but moving some of the HTML in the parent to the child directives solved the issue.  I don't understand why, but it is solved nonetheless.